# 2 optional integer parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My User controller action looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Choose(int? userId, int? locationId)
{

}
```

The url will look like:

```
/user/choose
```

or

```
/users/user/choose/{userId}/{locationId}
```

I tried to add this to my area routes:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "User_Choose",
    "Users/{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{locationId}",
        new { Controller = "Reward", action = "Choose", userId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now if I go to a URL like:

```
/users/user/choose/123/456
```

I see that the userId parameter has a value, but the locationId is always null.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Do you have any other routes mapped?

Comment: You probably need to set `locationId = UrlParameter.Optional` in the anonymous object you are creating.

Comment: What about `/Users/User/Choose/123/456` It may be case sensitive...

Comment: No route parameters are case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

The fix might lie here:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "User_Choose",
    "Users/{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{locationId}",
        new { controller = "Reward", action = "Choose", userId = UrlParameter.Optional, locationId = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

You must specify what brackets mean with anonymous object i.e. set their default values.

**EDIT:** Actually there is no problem in your code.
My controller:

```
namespace WebApplication3.Areas.Users.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Users/User
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Choose(int? userId, int? locationId)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

UsersAreaRegistration.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication3.Areas.Users
{
    public class UsersAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Users";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "User_Choose",
                "Users/{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{locationId}",
                    new { controller = "Reward", action = "Choose", userId = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
namespace WebApplication3
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

And I always get both values with url you provided in the `Chose()` method. The actual problem might lie in your namespaces.

Comment: Very nice code, but I tested the OP code and is working very fine withoud `locationId = UrlParameter.Optional`.

Comment: Actually I'm getting it fine too without that.